# Why I get error when application starts?

Tags: angularjs

I use angularjs version 1.6.4 in my project.
I have this error in console debugger when my application starts:

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=reports

Here is my main module:

```
angular.module('main', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ngResource', 'reports', 'ui.grid'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/reports', { templateUrl: 'app/ReportTrafficDepart/App/Reports/templates/reports.html', controller: 'reportsController' })
    }]);
```

Here is reports module:

```
angular.module('reports', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ngResource', 'ui.grid']);
```

Here is reports controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("reports").controller('reportsController');

    function reportsController() {
        var t = "test";
    }
})();
```

Here how I load all the files dependency and module in my Layout page:

```
        @Scripts.Render(
                 "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/angular-touch.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/ui-grid.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/xml2json.js",
                 "~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js",

                 //main
                 "~/app/ReportTrafficDepart/App/Main/main.module.js",
                 //Reports        
                 "~/app/ReportTrafficDepart/App/Reports/controller/reports.controller.js",
                 "~/app/ReportTrafficDepart/App/Reports/reports.module.js")
```

Any idea why I get error above?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to add a controller to the reports module **before** you define the reports module.

Define the module first, then you can add controllers to it.

I.e. make sure the `reports.module.js` file is loaded **before** the `reports.controller.js` file, and not after.

Comment: Edit your question and post the source of the HTML file (right-click - view page source). Also, replae angular.min.js by angular.js, and post the error message you get.

Answer (score 1):

Your main module is dependent on **`reports`** module, so load the reports module initially before loading **`main module`**.Change the order as follows,

```
 "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
 "~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js",
 "~/Scripts/angular-touch.min.js",
 "~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js",
 "~/Scripts/ui-grid.min.js",
 "~/Scripts/xml2json.js",
 "~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js",
 "~/app/ReportTrafficDepart/App/Reports/reports.module.js"
 "~/app/ReportTrafficDepart/App/Reports/controller/reports.controller.js",
 "~/app/ReportTrafficDepart/App/Main/main.module.js",
```